# Trying to develop a facebook application

Tags: facebook

I want to start working on developing a facebook application but honestly have no idea where to begin. I looked at facebook's tutorial Can anyone point me towards a good tutorial so I can get started?

Thanks in advance
--mosquito

Comment: This question is to broad to be answered. Please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the best way to start is http://developers.facebook.com/ .

However if you want a quickstart, here are some tips:

1. Create your application (https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
2. Get your Facebook App ID/API Key and Secret Code.
3. Start Playing with Facebook Graph (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) in your Website (Javascript is a good starting point)
4. Once you played a while with Javascript and FB Graph, you'll be almost ready to go deep and create your own Application, canvas, etc., baby steps.

   ```
   <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
       appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
       status     : true, 
       cookie     : true,
       xfbml      : true,
       oauth      : true,
     });

     FB.api('/me', function(user) {
       if (user) {
         var image = document.getElementById('image');
         image.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
         var name = document.getElementById('name');
         name.innerHTML = user.name
       }
     });
   };

   (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
   ```

Comment: thank you carlos - that's pretty much what i was looking for. I've looked through the facebook developers site and their tutorials are all outdated, so I guess I'll just have to play and fiddle around with it for a while.